# does showing regular users the mysqli_errno considered safe or not?

Tags: php, mysql, security, error-code

I thought of sending MySQL error number using `mysqli_errno()` to a page telling the user that 
'there was an error with this code if this persists, please send this code to the site owner at email@example.com'.

I have seen a lesson that shows how to throw the mysqli_error() message to an error page, but I don't want the user to see the descriptive text, just the code.

Is this safe?

will showing the MySQL error code not threaten my site's security?

I want to get benefit from the error code to solve the problem. Do you suggest other techniques?

Comment: Safe or not, it's totally useless. Your user cannot debug your codebase or fix your server :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you,  they can't, but I thought the might help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not do this. Exposing details of your server's infrastructure is a security flaw. If an attacker knows that you're using mysql they may attempt mysql exploits. Best keep this information private.

Rather, you should create a service interface for your clients that they can log on to to read their error logs. You could generate a unique id for each error (guid), and save the error in a database keyed by the same guid. You can then return that guid to the client someway (as a header, for example). Your client can get hold of this and use your admin/error service to query the database for the error associated with that id.

I know this sounds convoluted, but security is convoluted. There are ways to simplify this -- COTS tools for example, but they all basically follow this pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I won't do it. Do you thin of a better solution?

Comment: I've responded as part of the answer. Thanks for suggesting that it could be better.

Comment: Thank you, I am kind of a beginner, but I would use your technique in the future when I advance my skills, best regards :)